# Why can't I add a Joint to the Scene physicsWorld in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to add a joint to the scene physicsWorld property, but I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. This is the code I'm using.

```
SKPhysicsJointFixed *fixedJoint = [SKPhysicsJointFixed jointWithBodyA:self.mousePoint.physicsBody bodyB: self.box.physicsBody anchor:touchPoint];

[self.physicsWorld addJoint:fixedJoint]; // Error happens here.
```

I'm calling it when a touch begins. Does anyone know whats going on?

Comment: Are mousePoint and box' physics bodies non-nil? Is the created fixedJoint nil? Is there any possibly related error message in the log?

Comment: Yes. I set mousePoint to a new SKShapeNode when the scene initWithSize:size is called. But I set the path to the SKShapeNode when the touch begins.

Comment: No, I meant: Have you verified using a breakpoint and debugger that the input parameters to SKPhysicsJointFixed are non-nil and that the returned fixedJoint is also non-nil?

Answer (score 15):

i encountered the same problem with you, the answer is very easy, 
just add the node to the scene before adding it to the physicsworld.

Comment: Agreed - same problem and this is the correct solution. In my case the node that was not yet attached was further up the tree so it took a bit of finding. +1, but if someone with more power can mark John's answer as correct I think that would be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. 
and the problem was:I forgot to add physicsBody to one of the nodes.
so i was passing "nil". and this was cause of my error.

try something like this:

```
node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: node.size)
```

Answer (score 0):

i have simular problem and it was happening because i was creating physics body before i have added the node to the scene.

try this
1 init node
2 add it to the scene
3 attach physics body
4 do whatever with joints

(i was switching 2 and 3 and it hadn't working